# ping with timestamp in mininet

Tags: timestamp, ping, unix-timestamp, mininet

I am trying to find out timestamp with ping command in mininet. Whenever I ping some host I got results similar to the following:

```
mininet> h1 ping h2
PING 10.0.0.2 (10.0.0.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=1.17 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=1.48 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.426 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.059 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=0.089 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=6 ttl=64 time=0.301 ms
```

but I want results something like this;

```
10:13:29.421875 Reply from 10.0.0.1: bytes=32 time=3889ms TTL=238
10:13:29.468750 Reply from 10.0.0.1: bytes=32 time=3738ms TTL=238
10:13:29.468751 Reply from 10.0.0.1: bytes=32 time=3379ms TTL=238
```

I can easily get this from linux command prompt but I am not getting it from mininet prompt. Is it possible to get timestamp with ping on mininet prompt.

Answer (score 0):

maybe it can be done through python script calling it from mininet promt

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
man ping
```

you will see one of the option is:

```
-D     Print timestamp (unix time + microseconds as in gettimeofday) before each line.
```

If you don't want to call any scripts from mininet, you can simply get the timestamp by this:

```
h1 ping h2 -D
```

This commands will display a UNIX timestamp before the result such as:

```
[1524446605.745780] 64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=3.70 ms
[1524446606.743407] 64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.479 ms
[1524446607.743291] 64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.070 ms
[1524446608.742918] 64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.076 ms
[1524446609.743254] 64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=0.070 ms
[1524446610.743064] 64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=6 ttl=64 time=0.067 ms
[1524446611.743123] 64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=7 ttl=64 time=0.072 ms
[1524446612.742662] 64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=8 ttl=64 time=0.072 ms
```

You can just find some methods to transfer this timestamp to the form you prefer